# How to get matching pixels of 2 cameras?

Tags: python

I have a set up a scene where 2 cameras are looking at the same object. The cameras are separated by some distance. I need a python script to find the correspondence of the pixels in the two images produced by the two cameras. More concretely, I want to find pixel coordinate (u, v) in the first camera's image and its corresponding pixel coordinate (u', v') in the second camera's image such that (u, v) and (u', v') both correspond to the same world point (x, y, z). Please help.

Comment: This is apparently not related to Blender but more a computer vision problem. Or is it 2 cameras in Blender?

Comment: 2 cameras in blender.